# Understanding Haskell code which applies the `tails` function to an infinite list within a list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, primes, infinite

After submitting my solution to Project Euler's [problem 50](https://projecteuler.net/problem=50) earlier today, I was scrolling through the problem's forums, taking a look at other folks' solutions/execution times.

After a while, I started to feel quite proud of my code which solved it in ~3 seconds (my code used the `Primes` library and was compiled with `O2`)...

...and then I came across the code below which solved it in ~0.05 seconds...in interpreted mode (i.e., `ghci`).

**Can someone explain how/why the code below solves this particular problem?**

The mind-twisting part is the application of the `tails` function to the infinite list of primes (`primes`) within a list comprehension.  I'm having a hard time understanding how we guarantee that we look at all possible sublists of consecutive primes and not just those generated by `tails`.

(My usual strategy of trying bits and pieces of code in `ghci` doesn't work in this situation because `primes` is infinite...)

**The problem:** We're asked to find the largest prime number below 1,000,000 which is the result of summing consecutive prime numbers.  For example, the largest prime number below 100 which is the sum of consecutive primes is 41 (2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13).

```
import Data.List (tails)
import Data.Numbers.Primes

under n xs = takeWhile (< n) xs

takeUntil p xs = foldr (\x r-> if p x then [x] else x:r) [] xs

res :: [((Int, Int), (Int, Int))] 
-- ((top_length, sums_to), (total_length, starting_prime))

res = [(r,(length s,x)) | (x:xs) <- tails primes
                        , let s = zip [1..]
                                $ under 100
                                $ scanl (+) x xs
                        , let r = ...] 

main = mapM_ print $ takeUntil ...
```

Comment: What does "obv compiled with `O2`" mean?  Is OBV some sort of special compilation tool?

Comment: obv = obviously :P (took it out), had only intended to highlight how badly my own code performed relative to the code posted above.

Comment: Perhaps you should post your code and we can tell you why it runs so much slower.

Comment: the entry does state that "detecting primality by trial division", and finding "primes by sieve of Eratosthenes" are "both loaded from a compiled module", though.

Comment: btw [the problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=50) asks for *"the sum of the most consecutive primes?"* i.e. the longest, not the biggest.

Comment: Sorry gents (and ladies), am getting slammed at work; in fact, I spent a good portion of Thxgiving weekend in the office.  I prefer following up after I've had a chance to digest and do my own homework (which I haven't had a chance to do yet).  I will respond in more detail shortly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there's no problem with taking `tails` of `primes`, because Haskell is *lazy* (the evaluation is *on-demand*).

Here specifically there's even less problem because each sublist is trimmed with `under 100 = takeWhile (< 100)` - only a finite prefix is taken.

`(x:xs) <- tails primes` just goes through all suffixes of `primes` - i.e. *primes* starting from `x=2`; then *primes* starting from `x=3`, then `5,7,11, ...`. The pattern only demands the  head element `x`, and the tail `xs` of the primes list, and even their values aren't immediately requested, only the so-called *"spine"* of *primes* list is forced, 1 notch at a time (of course making sure `primes` starts with at least one element `x` will automatically compute the actual value of `x`, but that's another matter).

So `(x:xs) <- tails primes` operates on consecutive suffixes of the primes list. Try `tails [1..10]` to see what's going on there.

---

When you type

```
GHCi> primes
```

at the GHCi prompt, you're actually requesting *all* the elements of `primes` list to be printed as the output. But

```
GHCi> under 100 primes
```

will only request those below 100, and not more than one element after that. It uses the built-in `takeWhile` that examines elements in `primes`, one after another, until one is found that fails the predicate (in this case, is bigger than 100). The terminating element is not included in the result.

The user-defined `takeUntil` differs from that only in that it also includes the terminating element in its result (and the meaning of predicate is flipped - it signals when to stop).

The `scanl (+)` is the usual way to calculate the sequence of partial sums of a sequence:

```
Prelude> scanl (+) 1 [2..10]
[1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55]
```

---

The code

```
 [ (r,(length s,x)) | (x:xs) <- tails primes
                    , let s = zip [1..]
                            $ under 100
                            $ scanl (+) x xs
                    , let r = last $ filter (isPrime.snd) s]
```

means:

```
for each suffix of primes        -- [[2,3,5,7...],[3,5,7,11...],...]
  let 
    x  = head suffix             -- for all primes from x
    xs = tail suffix             --   i.e. xs
    t1 = scanl (+) x xs          -- calculate partial sums
    t2 = under 100 t1            -- stopping when the sum reaches 100
    s  = zip [1..] t2            -- index each sum by the length of subsequence,
    t3 = filter (isPrime.snd) s  -- keep only such that summed to a prime,
    r  = last t3                 -- and take the one created from the
  in                             --    longest subsequence, starting from x
    emit (r,(length s,x))        -- and collect the data
```

So we get the list of entries *`((top_length, sums_to), (total_length, starting_prime))`* for each consecutive prime number, *`starting_prime = 2,3,5,7,11, ...`* .

The `takeUntil` expression in `main` determines when it's okay to stop, as there's no possibility of improving the result anymore.

Comment: I am ashamed to say that it took me a long time to truly understand how this code works.  Ironically, your explanation of inits/tails/scanl "clicked" for me when I was working on another Euler problem earlier today (in which I ended up using a similar pattern of functions on an infinite list).  Then when I came back to this code, it was suddenly crystal clear!  Not the first time I've had such an experience with Haskell :)  Thank you again for the explanation.  (Am certainly looking fwd to reading more of your solutions in the problem forums!)

Answer (score 1):

To work around the infinite list problem, just define:

```
primesUpTo100 = takeWhile (< 100) primes
```

and use `primesUpTo100` in the definition of `res` in place of `primes`.

Next, change the definition of `res` to return different values so you can see what is going on, e.g.:

```
res = do
  (x:xs) <- tails primesUpTo100
  let s = zip [1..] $ under 100 $ scanl (+) x xs
  let r = last  $ filter (isPrime.snd) s
  return (x, take 10 xs, s)
```

Now you can see what `s` is and how it is related to `x` and the first 10 elements of `xs`.

If the list `res` is too long just evaluate `take 10 res`. Another tip is to define a helper function:

```
import Control.Monad
pp xs = forM_ xs print
```

This will print out a list which each element on a new line which should make things easier to read. E.g.:

```
pp (take 10 res)
```

Using all of these ideas I bet you can figure it out. It's actually a brute-force search for the longest sequence, but the use of `scanl` might avoid the recalculation of sums.